# Error SocketPermission when running ItemSimilarity method - Mahout 1.0

Tags: apache-spark, mahout

In java code, I call this method with simple command below

```
ItemSimilarityDriver.main(new String[] {
                "--input", InFile,
              "--output", OutPath,
              "--master", masterUrl,
              "--filter1", "purchase",
              "--filter2", "view",
              "--inDelim", ",",
              "--itemIDColumn", "2",
              "--rowIDColumn", "0",
              "--filterColumn", "1"});
```

Then I got the following error when running:

```
Failed to instantiate [ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext]
Reported exception:
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.net.SocketPermission$1.run(SocketPermission.java:1217)
    at java.net.SocketPermission$1.run(SocketPermission.java:1209)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketPermission.initEphemeralPorts(SocketPermission.java:1208)
    at java.net.SocketPermission.<clinit>(SocketPermission.java:235)
    at sun.security.util.SecurityConstants.<clinit>(SecurityConstants.java:259)
    at sun.security.provider.PolicyFile$4.run(PolicyFile.java:688)
    at sun.security.provider.PolicyFile$4.run(PolicyFile.java:684)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.provider.PolicyFile.initStaticPolicy(PolicyFile.java:684)
    at sun.security.provider.PolicyFile.initPolicyFile(PolicyFile.java:510)
    at sun.security.provider.PolicyFile.init(PolicyFile.java:464)
    at sun.security.provider.PolicyFile.<init>(PolicyFile.java:322)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at java.security.Policy.getPolicyNoCheck(Policy.java:195)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain.implies(ProtectionDomain.java:272)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:350)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.util.Loader$1.run(Loader.java:50)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.util.Loader$1.run(Loader.java:47)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.util.Loader.<clinit>(Loader.java:46)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.findURLOfDefaultConfigurationFile(ContextInitializer.java:119)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:148)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:85)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:129)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:108)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:302)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:276)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
    at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:40)
    at org.apache.mahout.sparkbindings.package$.<init>(package.scala:40)
    at org.apache.mahout.sparkbindings.package$.<clinit>(package.scala)
    at org.apache.mahout.drivers.MahoutSparkDriver.start(MahoutSparkDriver.scala:81)
    at org.apache.mahout.drivers.ItemSimilarityDriver$.start(ItemSimilarityDriver.scala:128)
    at org.apache.mahout.drivers.ItemSimilarityDriver$.process(ItemSimilarityDriver.scala:211)
    at org.apache.mahout.drivers.ItemSimilarityDriver$$anonfun$main$1.apply(ItemSimilarityDriver.scala:116)
    at org.apache.mahout.drivers.ItemSimilarityDriver$$anonfun$main$1.apply(ItemSimilarityDriver.scala:114)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at org.apache.mahout.drivers.ItemSimilarityDriver$.main(ItemSimilarityDriver.scala:114)
    at org.apache.mahout.drivers.ItemSimilarityDriver.main(ItemSimilarityDriver.scala)
```

I have tried to add

```
grant{
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

in java.policy but it's still not effect. The problem seems to be related to permission but I really don't know exactly what it is here.

Please help me!

Comment: This seems to be happening with Java 7 due to Logback on MacOSX (Yosemite). With Java 8 I get `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.validate(XMLDTDValidator.java:1099)`